# IIS Rewrite rule multiple react apps

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have several spa applications under one address and one port.

Each application can be accessed, but not sub-addresses or sub-levels.

- address1:port1/a/b/spa1 : ok
- address1:port1/c/d/spa2 : ok

but

- address1:port1/a/b/spa1/sub : error
- address1:port1/c/d/spa2/sub/sub?aaa=aaa : error

I set web.config in IIS root directory.

Can't access sub-route

How do I set up the web.config in root directory or sp1, sp2 directory

My web.config set in address1:port1 directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <rules> 
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true"> 
                    <match url=".*" /> 
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" /> 
                </rule> 
            </rules> 
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post the details of the error, or you can also use the failed request tracer to see the details of the request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: If you have N React web apps hosted on IIS under a single site, then you need N rewrite rules for each of them to ensure the URLs are properly routed. Right now clearly a single rule won't work at all.